# Extract values from two columns of two tables (Sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two separate tables like

```
tab.1    
col.1
1
2
3
```

```
tab.2
col.1 col.2
56    77
66    99
88    09
```

I want result to get first tab.1 values and second tab.2 col.1 values like

```
1 56
2 66
3 88
```

Union all puts second tab. values after first tab. values but I need like in above mentioned style.

Comment: Please include the schema of both tables in the question. You need an inner join, but it's unclear what's the key should be without knowing some more context.

Comment: Are the two tables related? if yes, isn't the `inner join` is what you need?

Comment: @JQSOFT No, two tables are not related and I want second tab. values in front of first one.

Comment: @ybungalobill INNER JOIN needs some related criteria. But I don't have any and wanna join ...

Comment: @Maya: you are aware that tables don't have an intrinsic order in them, right?

Answer (score 2):

If the results depend on the numeric order of the values of the 2 columns then use `row_number()` window function:

```
select t1.col1 tab1col1, t2.col1 tab2col1
from (select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn from tab1) t1  
inner join (select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn from tab2) t2  
on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/afSL4MZh1xfZ5KDdBaRrr6/0).
If the values of `col1` in `tab1` are actually: 1, 2, 3, ... then you don't need `row_number()` for `tab1`:

```
select t1.col1 tab1col1, t2.col1 tab2col1
from tab1 t1  
inner join (select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn from tab2) t2  
on t1.col1 = t2.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/afSL4MZh1xfZ5KDdBaRrr6/1).
Results:

```
| tab1col1 | tab2col1 |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 56       |
| 2        | 66       |
| 3        | 88       |
```

Comment: although you provide demo but first query give me syntax error.

Comment: [02:09:34] Error while executing SQL query on database 'datamaster': near "(": syntax error

Comment: I can't tell why you get this error. Maybe your version of SQLite is previous than 3.25.0 and does not support window functions?